# ImportError: No module named grequests "VS 2019 Windows"

Tags: python

ImportError: No module named grequests

i have this error in python project using visual studio 2019
install the library
libevent-2.1.11-stable
and I was able to compile it, that is, in the directory I found 3 files from the library

libevent

libevent_core

libevent_extras

in the project it keeps giving an error and when I give project properties it doesn't open any window to indicate the library, does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the missing module.

```
pip install grequests
```